# How to return actual cell component bounds in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a custom renderer in a `JTable` to display `JCheckbox`es for `boolean`s.  However, this causes a slight issue because when the user clicks in the table cell, but not in the checkbox, the checkbox is still checked.

Is there a way I can return the bounds of the actual `JCheckbox` that is rendered by the `JTable` at a particular point so I can determine if the click is within the bounds of the `JCheckbox`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I *want* it to check the box even if I miss it by a little bit.  Although if the cell gets big for other reasons (like a big title) I can see it being a slight annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the state of the checkbox is the responsibility of the Editor, not the Renderer.  If you use [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html), you don't need to write your own code.

I may be wrong but I think this is the default behaviour for any column that has a type of `Boolean.class` (as determined by the `TableModel`). So you don't need to write any rendering/editing code, just ensure that your model returns the correct column type and the column will be rendered as checkboxes and edited with checkboxes.

**EDIT:** Maybe I was confused by what you were asking.  Having seen Paul's comment on the question, I have to agree that the checkbox *should* be toggled if you click anywhere within the table cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `JCheckBox` as the component returned from the `TableCellEditor`, then it'll be stretched to fit or something else (it doesn't appear to be specified). So, the obvious thing to do is put it in a `JPanel`, and that let it be stretched, leaving how to allocate space to a `LayoutManager` of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just did similar thing this afternoon.

Here's my trick, for `JTree`. My checkbox is on the right most or the row.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

int x = e.getX();
int y = e.getY();
int row = getRowForLocation(x, y);

Rectangle rect = getRowBounds(row);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height + 2, rect.height);
if (rect2.contains(x, y)) ....  // The click is on the checkbox
```